# Java JFileChooser Back Button

Tags: java, swing, button, user-interface, jfilechooser

I just implemented the Java JFileChooser into my program and was wondering if There is a back button that can be added. In most file choosers in programs such as Microsoft Word or Photoshop, you can traverse back a directory. This option is very useful and was wondering if there is any way to do this.

Comment: I should of mentioned that I am using a mac. Here is a Gyazo of the File Chooser I am getting. I would like there to be a back button in the top left corner -> http://gyazo.com/930ef424500e36e829be30231b3046a8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really up to the look and feel, Windows look and feel does have a back button.

Comment: please check edit. For some reason the default file chooser does not have a back button.

Comment: The Gyazo post is how it looks now with no back button.

Comment: @JakeRunzer Read about `JFileChooser`'s `accessory` property, were you can add a custom component to your chooser.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you see if you use **System** Look and Feel on Windows (Back Button included).

[image: File Chooser]

```
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
        UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
```

Answer (score 2):

the function you desire is already present in the GUI,if you are implementing a JFileChooser.